# Spark Scala java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: while executing fat jar in CDH 5.16

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sbt, cloudera-cdh

I am using `CDH 5.16` which have `Spark 1.6.0`, `scala 2.10.5` and `java 1.8`.
I am trying to run a spark code by creating `FAT jar` from my local system using `sbt`.

But when i am running the spark submit on the cluster, i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaUniverse$JavaMirror;
        at salesSample$.main(salesSample.scala:24)
        at salesSample.main(salesSample.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My spark code is fairly simple as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext,SaveMode}


case class categories_schema(CategoryID: String, CategoryName: String, Description: String )
case class products_schema(ProductID: String, CategoryID: String, ProductName: String, SupplierID: String)

object salesSample {

  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val conf:SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("salessample").setMaster("local")
    val sc:SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)


    import sqlContext.implicits._



    val categories_data = sc.textFile("hdfs://url/user/ak_bng/categories").map(_.split(",")).map(p => categories_schema(p(0),p(1),p(2))).toDF()
    val product_data=sc.textFile("hdfs://url/user/ak_bng/products").map(_.split(",")).map( p=> products_schema(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3))).toDF()

   categories_data.registerTempTable("categories_data")
   product_data.registerTempTable("product_data")

   val prod_order_sql="""select distinct p.ProductID,p.ProductName,c.categoryname,
                          oh.OrderDate,oh.Freight,oh.OrderID,oh.ShipperID,
                          od.Quantity,od.Sales,Discount,od.COS,od.GP,p.CategoryID,
                          oh.Updated_time as oh_Updated_time,od.Updated_time as od_Updated_time
                          from prod p 
                          inner join ordrd od on p.productID=od.productID
                          inner join ordrh oh on od.OrderID=oh.OrderID
                          inner join cat c on c.categoryID=p.categoryID
                       """  

   categories_data.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("hdfs://url/user/hive/warehouse/product_order_temp2")
   sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I had a previous setup of Hadoop standalone in the same RHEl server and i was able to execute the jar build through SBT.

On googling i found out this is a version issue. I have corrected them but still couldnt quite figure out what is the issue.

Below is the content of my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "Simple_Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0" % "provided"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I tried changing the version of `Scala` to `2.10.0`,`2.10.5` and `2.10.6`.
All gave the same result.

Below is my `plugin.sbt` file content:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
```

I am using `Scala IDE` to write the code.

Can someone please help me in figuring out whats the issue here.

Comment: What version of Spark and Scala is being used in the cluster? You need to match those.

Comment: spark version is 1.6.0 and scala is 2.10.5 in the cluster (i have mentioned it at the beginning). i have matched them in the sbt file , created eclipse files again,assembled them again and ran the spark submit command in cluster after moving the jar. But same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this. It seems like the version of scala was not changed even after changing the same in `.sbt` file. In the `target` folder where the folder where the assembled `jar` file will be created was still named `2.11` instead of `2.10`.
So i created a new `sbt` project for the same spark code, compiled it, recreated `eclipse` files(i am using `scala ide`) and then assembled it. The new `jar` is working fine now.